# Errors while creation of Image for Tizen RD-PQ Reference Device

Tags: tizen

I've compiled the Tizen 2.2 source code, out of 706 packages I got around 704 Packages successfully build. The two packages which are getting failed are systemd and privacy-popup.

When I'm trying to create a image from this build for RD-PQ device I get the following errors for some packages.

```
INFO: Installing: dosfstools-2.11-1.ar +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [716/725]
INFO: Installing: bluetooth-firmware-b +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [717/725]
INFO: Installing: unzip                +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [718/725]
INFO: Installing: gettext-runtime      +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [719/725]
/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libSEC_OMX_Vdec.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libSEC_Resourcemanager.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libsrpapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libcscexynos4.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libsecosal.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libSEC_OMX_Core.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libsecmfcencapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libsecbasecomponent.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libSEC_OMX_Venc.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libSEC_OMX_Adec.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libsecmfcdecapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

INFO: Installing: libgomp              +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [720/725]
INFO: Installing: fsync-1.1-1.armv7l.r +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [721/725]
INFO: Installing: strace-4.5.20-3.armv +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [722/725]
INFO: Installing: vim-common-7.3.382-2 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [723/725]
INFO: Installing: net-tools            +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  [724/725]
INFO: Installing: eglibc-debugframe    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ [725/725]

[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_register_package,99] [smack] app_install(ui-gadget::client)
[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_register_package,101] [smack] app_install(ui-gadget::client), result = [0]
[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_setup_path,230] [smack] app_setup_path(ui-gadget::client, /opt/usr/apps/ui-gadget::client/shared/data, 2)
[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_setup_path,232] [smack] app_setup_path(), result = [-1]
[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_enable_permissions,196] [smack] app_enable_permissions(ui-gadget::client, 1)
[PKG_SMACK][E][__pkg_smack_enable_permissions,198] [smack] app_enable_permissions(ui-gadget::client, 1), result = [0]
INFO: Applying configurations ...
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369
passwd: password expiry information changed.
```

This is part of a log. At the end of the build I'm getting qemu: Unsupported syscall: 369 error. But after all this errors the image creation is successful and I'm getting the final tar.gz file in mic-output.

I've tried flashing the image on to the device and noticed that some of the functionality on the device are not working properly(e.g, the back button does not work in some of the applications)

Can anyone help me in solving the above error or if the above error is not to be considered since I'm getting the final image, is it a valid full image which I can use for RD-PQ device??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages **systemd** and **privacy-popup** were failing due to a rpm issue. The errors in the package can be removed by adding following line to the **spec** file as very first line

```
%define __debug_package %{nil}
```

This will solve the build issues of the packages which show **make** errors during compilation.